# Stuck On A Proof By Induction

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, inequality, induction

I need to prove [image] true for all integers greater than and equal to 1 using induction.

I'll skip the base case, and the inductive assumption, and jump straight to the inductive step:

[image]

=[image]

What I've done now is to say that [image] is less than [image]. But I don't know what to do from beyond there.

Comment: Can you type the steps out in MathJax please?

Comment: @RushabhMehta Okay, I've done that.

Comment: First hint: When proving an inequality "LHS $\leq$ RHS" (Left Hand Side $\leq$ Right Hand Side), start by writing LHS on its own. Then apply transformations that end up with RHS. Each transformation can only be an "=" or "$\leq$".

Comment: If you don't *have* to use induction, then the inequality is simply [AM-GM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means#The_inequality) for the first $n$ positive integers.

Comment: @I'm sorry but first, the problem says to use induction, and secondly, I don't know what AM-GM is.

Comment: @dxiv I'll read the link, but I would prefer a solution that uses induction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way by induction (as opposed to recognizing the inequality as just [AM-GM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means#The_inequality) for $1,2,\ldots,n\,$):   write the inequality to prove as $\,\color{blue}{2^n n! \le (n+1)^n}\,$, and take this to be the inductive assumption. Then, to prove the inductive step for $\,n+1\,$:

$$
2^{n+1} (n+1)! = 2(n+1) \cdot \color{blue}{2^n n!} \;\;\le\;\; 2(n+1)\cdot\color{blue}{(n+1)^n} = 2(n+1)^{n+1}
$$

To complete the inductive step, it is sufficient to show that the RHS is:

$$
2(n+1)^{n+1} \le (n+2)^{n+1} \;\;\iff\;\; \left(\frac{n+2}{n+1}\right)^{n+1} \ge 2 \;\;\iff\;\;\left(1 + \frac{1}{n+1}\right)^{n+1} \ge 2
$$

But the latter holds true by [Bernoulli's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality), which concludes the proof.

---

[ *EDIT* ]   To note that this particular case (positive integer exponent and $\ge1$ base) does not require the full power of Bernoulli's inequality, and the result can be simply derived from the binomial expansion $\,\left(1 + \frac{1}{n+1}\right)^{n+1}= 1 + \binom{n+1}{1}\cdot \frac{1}{n+1}+\ldots \ge 1 + (n+1)\cdot \frac{1}{n+1} = 2\,$.

Comment: In my opinion, Bernoulli's inequality is more elementary than the binomial theorem. Look at the complexity of the proofs.

Comment: @martycohen I completely agree, though in practice I found it to be a lot less taught than the binomial expansion, which why I added the last edit.